# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel display two items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Right now I have implemented `Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel` which displays one item and during transition, shows next element, so it looks like:

```
 [1]    /transition/   [2]    /transition/   [3]   ...
```

I have to display two items and after transition display second element with third one:

```
[1][2]  /transition/  [2][3]  /transition/  [3][4] ...
```

Is it even possible to achieve ?

I have tried to apply `active` class to the two elements on page load, but `Carousel` does not work anymore. Also using following CSS does not work:

```
.item.active + .item {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://bootply.com/78889

Comment: Not at all, because there are visible `[1][2]` and then `[3][4]`. I need to show `[1][2]`, `[2][3]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is quite simple.

`.item` class has two sizes of content - lets say `400px`. `.item-content` has `200px`:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="item-content">ITEM 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">ITEM 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">ITEM 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">ITEM 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
  width: 400px;
}
.carousel .item .item-content {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Right now we have to duplicate next items into current one to display two items like `[1][2]  [2][3]  [3][4]  [4][1]`

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.find('.item-content:first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
});
```

And modify carousel transition with:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
```

That's all.

Answer (score 8):

Hsz's solution worked fine until Twitter Bootstrap 3.3 where was added support for 3D transform which will override your styles for transition (left: 50% and left: -50%)

Therefore you have to override Twitter Bootstrap default transition styles with following css:

```
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

You may need to change 50% to 33% if you display 3 items etc

Comment: how would you change its transition speed ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bit old but I managed to solve it with,

```
#carousel-galleries{
  .carousel-inner{
    .item{
      @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
        @include transition-transform(0.6s ease-in-out);
        @include backface-visibility(hidden);
        @include perspective(1000);

        &.next,
        &.active.right {
          @include translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
          left: 0;
        }
        &.prev,
        &.active.left {
          @include translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
          left: 0;
        }
        &.next.left,
        &.prev.right,
        &.active {
          @include translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          left: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is 4 items advance by 1,  bootstrap-sass 3.3.1 with compass

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works well but it breaks when there is an odd number of carousel items.  I added some jquery to make it work for odd and even

```
if ($(this).siblings(':last')) {
    $(this).siblings(':first').find('.item-content:first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
}
else
{
    next.find('.item-content:first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));   
}
```