# Transition Issues with Bootstrap 3 Multi Carousel Advance 1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, transition, multiple-columns

I'm running into an issue with implementing a Bootstrap Carousel that displays 3 slides at once, but only advances 1 slide at a time. I am using a slightly modified version of the code found here: http://www.bootply.com/132400

When you view the bootply example the slides seem to transition smoothly 1 slide at a time. Now if you look at my example: http://www.odysseydesignstudio.com/slidertest/

Mine seems to skip, or the existing slide moves and then disappears and then the rest moves in. The only changes I've made are to make the large screen view display 3 slides instead of 4, and adjusted the styles accordingly. I don't know if I did something incorrectly, but I don't think I did because if I remove my changes and put in the HTML directly from the example, I still see a skip on mine. I am at a loss as to what might be causing this so I am hoping someone might be able to give me a suggestion as to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this thread [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel display two items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613271/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-display-two-items).  Bootstrap 3.3 added support for 3d transform which'll means the example in your bootply probably will not work properly.